# Java DAO design - return MAP instead of POJO

Tags: java, dao

When is it appropriate to return a map instead of POJO?

The current old DAO that I have is returning a list of object, and each one is an array of objects. Each array basically is a key-value pair.

I am going to refactor it a bit either using a list of POJOs , which is how normal DAOs return, but my question is that since it is just a key value pair anyway, is it more appropriate to return a map?

Or the map transformation should be done in the service layer?

Also if I should follow the convention, what should I be naming such POJO?

Comment: You'll need to be more specific. Are you talking about a Web API, a Java interface, or something else? Are you using Spring/Jersey/Dropwizard?

Comment: Do you mean the consumer of the DAO? I am talking about DAO. Which framework is irrelevant? Let's say I am using spring

Comment: I'm talking about the consumer of whatever API you're discussing, and "DAO" isn't specific at all. Frameworks matter because of data conversions.